# .Net Application extrem slow. After killing svchost.exe it runs again fast. Any idea?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, x86-64

I've a C# .Net 3.5 Application (x86) running on Windows7 x64.

For any reason after a few days or weeks the App runs extremly slow.

All other Apps runs normal (also another C# .Net 3.5 Application (x86)).

After killing a few svchost.exe the Application runs normal again. Rebooting without killing svchost.exe also doesn't help. Probably Windows saves the state of svchost.exe. If I logoff the user and login again it also works again, without killing the svchost. On logoff the svchost is probably cleared.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve the problem?

Greets
Wowa

**EDIT:**

The Main-Form is just an MDI-Container with a Treeview on the left-side with static nodes.

The Application checks on start for Updates via networkpath (checks files creationdate), but this can't be the problem, because all other PC works without a problem.

After the Update every MDI-child-form takes 1-2 minutes to start, even a empty form.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, i've forgot, that the updating is no more done by this application, but by another, which has nothing to do with the app which runs slow.

The app which updates the slow app runs normal. It only updates the slow app if it isn't running.

But the slow App removes files in the local Temp-path. `System.IO.File.Delete()`

Comment: Some more info about your application? What is it doing?

Comment: I'm very sorry but my crystal ball is receiving maintenance today otherwise I could tell you exactly what your problem was

Comment: i'll edit my post with more details.

Comment: Sysinternals Process Explorer will let you see more information per svchost.exe process, such as specific command-line arguments per instance.  You can use that to track down the specific application causing your slowdown.

Comment: First of all, what does your MDI app has to do with svchost?

Comment: I don't know, but after I kill the svchost the app runs again normal.

Comment: Does your application use any funky resources: Sockets, services, files, anything like that? Also, what happens when you restart the application?

Comment: @Kobi : Yes, files. After restarting the application it still runs slow. After logoff or kill the svchost it runs normal again.

Comment: I have this *crazy* suspicion that you're not correctly handling the unmanaged resources that your app uses and/or creates. Killing `svchost.exe` or logging off and back on again probably releases handles that your program didn't. But without any source code, there's no way to tell.

Comment: @Cody Gray: The application only uses managed code.

Comment: Even after 2 Edits, this still is a bit like a "my vacuum cleaner starts to slow down until I unplug my TV" kind of question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any details or code as to how exactly your application checks for updates at startup, I'm going to guess that it's doing it on the UI thread (main thread), and blocking your application while doing it.

You mentioned that it's checking for updates via networkpath, I'm going to assume that you mean network share, in which case this might be the reason one of the `svchost` processes is acting up. Get [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), and use it to determine exactly which services are started by the offending svchost (by looking at the hint, or the Services tab in the process properties):

[image]

Comment: I can only check this if the problem comes up again. Yes, it's runs in the main thread. Oh I've forgot an importent point... i will edit my post. +1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could be related to virus scanning software.  If you have it installed, disable it and try the process again.

Comment: Tried this to, but this also didn't help. Stop activ scan and killed all process of the virus scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing has been weighing us down.
Acrobat InDesign CS5 ME ver. (x86 app)
We have tried and tried again (Win7 64; 2gb; 1gb video card). I have noticed scvhost @ 50,000 sitting in Taskmanager; killed it, but comes back. We haven't upgraded yet because of this.
We run the same app on XP-32, and also have some trouble, but that i more likely because of only 128mb video memory (2 P4 chips, 4gb mem).
I have peeked in ProExp but didn't know HOW to look. Thanks for the tip.
Hey, I'm a plain guy, not a pro programmer.